# Working with time in R

Tags: r

I am really struggling working with time in R and wondered whether anyone could help.

For a sample data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(Time = structure(1:9, .Label = c("07:55:40", "07:55:50", 
                                                      "07:56:00", "07:56:10", "07:56:20", "07:56:30", "07:56:40", "07:56:50", 
                                                      "07:57:00"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Time", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                            -9L))
```

I am using the following code lines to convert time to a format R recognises (start.time) and then adding 10 seconds to start.time to get end.time.

```
df$start.time <- strptime(df$Time, "%H:%M:%S")  ##Correct
df$end.time <- df$start.time + 10
```

R automatically adds todays date to both start and end.time which is not what I wanted - whilst I understand R would prefer to have a reference date as well, for my purposes, this is not needed.

How do I exclude the date?

Comment: Use the `lubridate` package to make things much easier. Then you can do `df$start.time + seconds(10)`.

Comment: Here's one way: `format(df$end.time, format="%H:%M:%S")` but I like the **chron** -package for this type of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `"times"` class in chron. It represents times in fractions of a day so 1 second is `1 / (24 * 60 * 60)`.  Note that all times must be less than 24:00:00 :

```
> library(chron)
> transform(df, Time = times(Time) + 10 / (24 * 60 * 60))
      Time
1 07:55:50
2 07:56:00
3 07:56:10
4 07:56:20
5 07:56:30
6 07:56:40
7 07:56:50
8 07:57:00
9 07:57:10
```

Comment: Thanks - this works on my example dataframe but why when I try this on my real data do I get a decimal number instead of a time?  When I ask R what class the input data is it says it is a factor (which is what it says for the example).  What's going wrong?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you have created the times, with factor as class. Anyway, here is my solution with `lubridate` packages.

First convert to time `period` class with `hms` function and then just add 10 seconds with the `seconds` function.

```
library(lubridate)
df$Time <- hms(df$Time)
df[2] <- df[1] + seconds(10)
head(df, 2)
        Time     Time.1
1 7H 55M 40S 7H 55M 50S
2 7H 55M 50S 7H 55M 60S
```